# Django voting results in double counting

Tags: python, django

Im trying to simply accomplish that a vote on a post gets count +1 if a user hits the like button on my site but for some reasone it counts not +1, instead it counts +2 if i hit the URL of that post:

views.py

```
def post_up_vote (request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if post.author == request.user:
                messages.error(request, 'You are trying to vote on a Post you created by your own. Thats not possible.')
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
            if Post_Vote.objects.filter(voter=request.user, voted=post).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'You already Voted this Post. Double votes are not allowed.')
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
            else:
                post.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
                post.save()
                Post_Vote.objects.create(voter=request.user, voted=post)
                messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Post.')
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong, please try again.')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong, please try again.')
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
up_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
down_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
...

class Post_Vote(models.Model):

voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
voted = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('voter', 'voted')

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/up-vote/$', app.post_up_vote, name='post_up_vote'),
```

template.html

```
 <a href="{% url 'post_up_vote' pk=post.pk %}"> <i class="btn success fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
```

if i create a new post on my site and vote on this post with a diffrent user then the original post author, then the voting counts +2 and not +1 and im not able to see any reason for that.

Comment: Hey, Can you check what is the `post.up_vote` value at the start of `else` and after `post.save()`? Couldn't able to find any glitch till now.

Comment: Okay i found something deep inside the following line on objects:
post.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
Manager isn't accessible via Post instances

Comment: Now the next question is why its not available?!

Comment: okay, maybe you can try `post.up_vote += 1`.

Comment: That again works. But why, still remains magic to me. Thx so far but isn't post.refresh_from_db() unneeded in that case?

Comment: If you create this as aswere i will mark this as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `post.up_vote += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

F() objects assigned to model fields persist after saving the model instance and will be applied on each save().

```
post.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
post.save()
post.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Still counts +2

Comment: If it is an ajax call, make sure it invokes once only.

Comment: Nope, its not a AJAX call and i hand't this issue before... Seems like ghost magic to me.

Comment: Is  there any signals running for models